# Error : import data tier application in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, importerror

When I'm trying to import a `.bacpac` file, I'm getting this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

> Could not import package.Warning SQL72012: The object [grc-2023-7-29-12-56_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [grc-2023-7-29-12-56_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 7609, Level 17, State 5, Line 2 Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>
> CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[UserTable]
> ([GroupOf] LANGUAGE 1033, [SEGroupOf] LANGUAGE 1033)
> KEY INDEX [PK_UserTable_1] ON [catalog1];

It says > Full-Text Search is not installed But my other db has full-text, I tried to install but I couldn't. I followed [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6841/add-full-text-search-sql-server/) link to install but full-text option is not in my setup.

Is there anything I'm missing? Or do I need to uninstall and re-install my SQL Server?

Thanks!